# WPF - Llenar un ComboBox con íconos de IconPacks dinámicamente

Tags: wpf, icons

Necesito llenar dinámicamente un ComboBox con una lista de Íconos de IconPacks (https://www.iconpacks.net/) que tengo almacenados en Base de Datos.

¿Qué tengo?:

1. Una tabla en Base de Datos llamada TbMSIcons con la siguiente estructura.

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TbMsIcons](
   [IdIcon] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Name] varchar NOT NULL,
   [IconPack] varchar NOT NULL,
   [IconKind] varchar NOT NULL,
   [Path] varchar NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_TbMsIcons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
   [IdIcon] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO

Sus datos quedarían algo así.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Una Clase que contendrá dicha estructura con las siguientes características.

   public class Icon : BindableBase {

   ```
    #region Propiedades

    /// <summary>
    /// Identificador del Ícono
    /// </summary>
    public int IdIcon {
        get => LcIntIdIcon;
        set => SetProperty(ref LcIntIdIcon, value);
    }
    private int LcIntIdIcon;

    /// <summary>
    /// Nombre del Ícono
    /// </summary>
    public string? Name {
        get => LcStrName;
        set => SetProperty(ref LcStrName, value);
    }
    private string? LcStrName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Nombre del IconPack
    /// </summary>
    public string? IconPack {
        get => LcStrIconPack;
        set => SetProperty(ref LcStrIconPack, value);
    }
    private string? LcStrIconPack;

    /// <summary>
    /// Nombre del IconKind
    /// </summary>
    public string? IconKind {
        get => LcStrIconKind;
        set => SetProperty(ref LcStrIconKind, value);
    }
    private string? LcStrIconKind;

    /// <summary>
    /// Path de la Imágen
    /// </summary>
    public string? Path {
        get => LcStrPath;
        set => SetProperty(ref LcStrPath, value);
    }
    private string? LcStrPath;

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtiene la expresión del objeto como una cadena de caracteres.
    /// </summary>
    public string Label {
        get => ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructores

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor con datos de la Base de Datos.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oDr"></param>
    public Icon(DataRow oDr) {

        Utils.SbSetObjectProperties(this, oDr);

    }

    #endregion
   ```

   }
3. La clase anterior se llena y todos los elementos contenidos dentro de la Tabla en SQL se almacenan en el Modelo de Datos en una colección del Tipo

`ObservableCollection<Icon> Icons;`

4. Además, en el mismo Modelo tengo otra variable de la siguiente forma:

`Icon SelectedIcon;`

Mi objetivo es que, el ComboBox se llene automáticamente con la lista de íconos guardados en la tabla. Para ésto, creé el ComboBox de la siguiente manera: NOTA: Uso un ViewModel como enlace de datos y un Model llamado LcModel que contiene cada variable que se enlazará.

```
<ComboBox Width="200"
    ItemsSource="{Binding LcModel.Icons}" SelectedItem="{Binding LcModel.SelectedIcon}">

</ComboBox>
```

Con eso, puedo crear un Itemtemplate dentro del ComboBox para agregar un TextBlock y un objeto imágen.

Ahora bien, tengo claro que, para poder usar los Íconos de IconPacks dentro de mi aplicación, puedo usar un objeto **Image** y setear su atributo **Source** de la siguiente forma.

```
<Image Source={IconPacks:MaterialImage Kind=Pencil, Brush=White} />
```

previamente haciendo referencia al objeto **IconPacks** en la cabecera de la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
xmlns:IconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
```

DUDA: Intenté hacer un Bind a la propiedad Kind del Source de la imagen, pero me salta un error indicando que dicha propiedad no es Bindable... supongo que la solución puede ir por usar los DataTemplates y DataTriggers dentro del ItemTemplate... pero sinceramente no estoy muy enterado de cómo funcionan éstos... por lo que ando un poco perdido. ¿Podría alguien darme una mano para hacer esto? Si existe alguna otra solución alternativa a lo que planteo, me agradaría escucharla... De antemano se los agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas un elemento `<Path>` en lugar de una `<image>` , algo así

```
<ComboBox Width="200"
    ItemsSource="{Binding LcModel.Icons}" SelectedItem="{Binding LcModel.SelectedIcon}">

  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="90"></ColumnDefinition>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>               
          <StackPanel Background="White">
              <Path Data="{Binding Path=Path }" StrokeThickness="1"  Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxHeight="70" MaxWidth="70" ></Path>
          </StackPanel>
          <Label Grid.Row="1" Width="90"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="80" TextAlignment="Center"   />
          </Label>                                              
     </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hola Yussef... Gracias por la respuesta... dame oportunidad para ponerla en práctica y te comento si me resulta... de entrada suena bien! Gracias!!

Comment: Comprobado!... Ésto me funciona... necesita algunos cambios para el diseño, pero me has dado la respuesta que buscaba. Muchísimas Gracias!

Comment: @Gabo77 Cuanto me alegro, suerte con tu proyecto!!!